# OneToOneField, unique and inheritance in Django

Tags: django, django-models

I would like to have a relationship between the User model and one of some different (but related) models, but this **must be with only** one of the available models e.g. different kinds of subscriptions but a User can only have one related.

I know I can solve this with a lot of custom checks but I want to know if there is a recommended or simple solution.

If I use inheritance and define a base model, let's put "BaseModel" with a OneToOneField to User, and from this model, they will inherit several: ModelA and ModelB,

```
class ModelBase(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="model_base")

class Meta:
    abstract = True


class ModelA(ModelBase):
    pass


class ModelB(ModelBase):
    pass
```

Django shows this error

```
Reverse accessor 'User.model_base' for 'models.ModelA.user' clashes with reverse accessor for 'models.ModelB.user'.
```

I understand that defining a different related_name in submodels solves this, but this does not maintain the "unique" condition.

What would be the best solution for this problem? Could I avoid using GenericForeignKeys?

Thank you!